# excel vba, deleting all names from a workbook without a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete all names from an excel workbook using VBA
without using a loop.

I'm currently using the code below, but this is very slow as there are several thousand names in the workbook.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
Sub deleteAllNames()
Dim xName As Name

For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
       xName.Delete
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: To delete the name, meaning named ranges?

Comment: yes, named ranges (some are named formulas, not sure if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 5):

Not possible without some complicated hacky way or messing with the XML, but this should be faster:

```
Dim i As Long
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
For i = ThisWorkbook.Names.Count To 1 Step -1
    ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Delete
Next
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: thanks! this speeded it up a bit (still slow but any gain helps)

Comment: @Charteris if it's really that slow, then I am guessing the slow part is not deleting the names, but Excel converting all references to the names into range references.

Comment: thanks -- is it possible to turn that conversion off?

Comment: not that I know of, but you can probably copy or save the formulas as text to a new file .. which will result in bunch of #REF! errors

Comment: on top of DNR, I have also tables. In this case, the code generates an error because of undefined ranges. I had to add "on error resume next" just before the deleting action, within the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem deleting all named ranges, the code was running very slowly. You can fix this by turning off the screen update and the calculation while the loop is running.

```
Sub deleteAllNames()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim xName As Name

For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
       xName.Delete
Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problema with "For Each xName In", it's use memory, and i have 160000 names in the stack, and VBA gets out of memory..

The FOR loop allow to pass trough all names, slow but works..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).